# Syntax error while loading data from SAP Hana with Python

Tags: python, hana

I have an issue loading data from SAP HANA via Python.
The code works fine when it is like:

```
connection = pyhdb.connect(|||credentials|||)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT "0COMP_CODE", "0VENDOR", "0REF_DOC_NO", "0BBP_INV_ID" FROM  "_SYS_BIC"."system-local.bw.bw2hana/ZFGL01MY" WHERE CAST( "0PSTNG_DATE" AS date) >= ADD_MONTHS( NEXT_DAY( LAST_DAY( CURRENT_DATE)), -2) and "0VENDOR" IS NOT NULL')
```

But when I'm trying to add condition like "0COMP_CODE" = 'B2B',

so it looks like that:

```
Connection = pyhdb.connect(|||credentials|||)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT "0COMP_CODE", "0VENDOR", "0REF_DOC_NO", "0BBP_INV_ID" FROM  "_SYS_BIC"."system-local.bw.bw2hana/ZFGL01MY" WHERE CAST( "0PSTNG_DATE" AS date) >= ADD_MONTHS( NEXT_DAY( LAST_DAY( CURRENT_DATE)), -2) and "0VENDOR" IS NOT NULL AND "0COMP_CODE" = 'B2B' ')
```

I'm getting `SyntaxError: invalid syntax.`

What I'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code which returns errors? It seems to be something related to quotes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to scape single quotes:

```
Connection = pyhdb.connect(|||credentials|||)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT "0COMP_CODE", "0VENDOR", "0REF_DOC_NO", "0BBP_INV_ID" FROM  "_SYS_BIC"."system-local.bw.bw2hana/ZFGL01MY" WHERE CAST( "0PSTNG_DATE" AS date) >= ADD_MONTHS( NEXT_DAY( LAST_DAY( CURRENT_DATE)), -2) and "0VENDOR" IS NOT NULL AND "0COMP_CODE" = \'B2B\' ')
```